# Finding the angles of rotation of a line in three-dimensional space knowing the coordinates

Tags: c#, math, vector, 3d

There is a line at which we know the coordinates of the extreme points. 
[image: coordinates]

We can also measure the distance between the starting and ending points.

```
delta_x:  -45.5
delta_y:  59
delta_z:  -4
```

```
delta_x1:  -38.5
delta_y1:  40.5
delta_z1:  17
```

The goal is to move the green line to the blue. The first action, knowing the distance to the extreme point(B and V), I move point B to point V. Now we need to determine at what angles the line should be rotated relative to point V so that it coincides with the blue one.

Coordinates and distances to points are slightly different, but do not pay attention to it.

The illustration is on the link:

I expressed the angles of rotation from the matrix of stratifying cosines during rotation with respect to x y z. But they think not true angles.
I also tried other formulas but they only work with positive changes in coordinates.

```
double rotx1 = -((t[2] * t1[1] - t1[2] * t[1]) / (t1[1] * t1[1] + t1[2] * t1[2]));
double rotx11 = Math.Asin(rotx1) / Math.PI * 180;
double roty1 = -((t[2] * t1[0] - t1[2] * t[0]) / (t1[0] * t1[0] + t1[2] * t1[2]));
double roty11 = Math.Asin(roty1) / Math.PI * 180;
double rotz1 = -((t[1] * t1[0] - t1[1] * t[0]) / (t1[0] * t1[0] + t1[1] * t1[1]));
double rotz11 = Math.Asin(rotz1) / Math.PI * 180;
Console.WriteLine("X=" + Convert.ToString(rotx11) + " Y=" + 
Convert.ToString(roty11) + " Z=" + Convert.ToString(rotz11));
```

or this

```
double[] pos = { 395, -0, 37, 90, 90, 0 };//The coordinates of the first marker.           
double[] pos1 = { 321, -0, 37, 90, 90, 0 };//The coordinates of the second marker.
double[] t = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
double[] t1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
double[] t2= { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

double x = -45.5;//Known changes in the coordinates of the point of the first marker
double y = 59;
double z = 33 ;

double x1 = -38.5;// Known changes in the coordinates of the point of the second marker
double y1 = 40.5;
double z1 = 54;

t[0] = pos[0] + x;
t[1] = pos[1] + y;
t[2] = pos[2] -4;
t[3] = pos[3];
t[4] = pos[4];
t[5] = pos[5];

t1[0] = pos1[0] + x1;
t1[1] = pos1[1] + y1;
t1[2] = pos1[2] + 17;
t1[3] = pos1[3];
t1[4] = pos1[4];
t1[5] = pos1[5];


double Ayx21 = Math.Atan2(t[1] - t1[1], t[0] - t1[0]) / Math.PI * 180;

double rotx = Math.Atan2(t[1] - t1[1], t[2] - t1[2]);

double roty1111 = -Math.Atan2((t[2] - t1[2]) * Math.Cos(rotx), (t[1] - t1[1]));

double rotz = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(roty1111), Math.Sin(rotx) * Math.Cos(rotx)) / Math.PI * 180;
double rotx11111 = (rotz) - (Ayx21);
double roty = -Math.Atan2((t[2] - t1[2]) * Math.Cos(rotx), (t[1] - t1[1])) / Math.PI * 180;
t2[0] = pos[0] + x;
t2[1] = pos[1] + y;
t2[2] = pos[2] + z ;//убрать потом -37
t2[3] = (rotx11111);
t2[4] = (90 + roty);

 t2[5] = (180 + rotz);
string position1 = Convert.ToString(t2[0]).Replace(',', '.');
string position2 = Convert.ToString(t2[1]).Replace(',', '.');
string position3 = Convert.ToString(t2[2]).Replace(',', '.');
string angle1 = Convert.ToString(t2[3]).Replace(',', '.');
string angle2 = Convert.ToString(t2[4]).Replace(',', '.');
string angle3 = Convert.ToString(t2[5]).Replace(',', '.');
Console.WriteLine("[" + Convert.ToString(position1) + "," + Convert.ToString(position2) + "," + Convert.ToString(position3) + "," + Convert.ToString(angle1) + "," + Convert.ToString(angle2) + "," + Convert.ToString(angle3) + "]");
```

Comment: Use i.stack.imgur.com for image, cause it's for stackoverflow.

Comment: Hey I'm not 100% sure, but I think to calculate the angle of 2 vectors, you would first have to move one of them, so they are actually able to form an angle. And then you should be able to calculate this using Acos function. Something like: angle = acos(v1 * v2 / |v1| * |v2|)

Comment: An easier and more robust (using existing library functionality) way of doing this is to construct the *quaternion* that represents the rotation from the green line to the blue line, and convert it into a matrix.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog http://marctenbosch.com/quaternions/ 
Yes, I also found an article about quaternion but I do not know how to write an algorithm in c #

Answer (score 0):

```
public static float AngleBetween(this vec3 u, vec3 v, bool returndegrees = true)
    {
        u = u.Normalize();
        v = v.Normalize();
        var ratio = u.Dot(v);
        float theta;
        if (ratio < 0)
            theta = (float)Math.PI - 2.0f * (float)Math.Asin((-u - v).GetNorm() * 0.5f);
        else
            theta = 2.0f * (float)Math.Asin((u - v).GetNorm() * 0.5f);

        return returndegrees ? (float)(180 * theta / Math.PI) : theta;
    }
```